RabbitMQ Bidirectional Replication
I have two physical servers with each having their own IP and both the servers is running their own RabbitMQ instance. I need to implement bidirectional replication in these RabbitMQ instances , suppose if a msg is inserted in queue of server 1 , then it should be automatically replicated to queue of server2 and vice versa.
If message is consumed from queue of server 1 then the message should be removed from queue of both the servers.
I am very new to RabbitMQ and not getting how to implement this , I have tried exploring clustering and federation but I didn't get much.
It would be a great help.
I need a configuration like that exist in Active-Active DB replication, suppose if something is inserted in DB1 then it will get replicated in DB2 and if something get removed from DB1 or DB2 then it will get removed from both.
I need a similar configuration in my 2 RabbitMQ instance running on 2 different server. If some message 'A' get inserted in Queue 1 then it get replicated in Queue 2 also and if a message is consumed from queue 2 or queue 1 then it get consumed from both.

Take a look into Quorum Queues: https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/quorum-queues
